# Angular SSR website redirects to login page before going to actual path

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I use Angular SSR and when I refresh on the pages, it goes to the login page first and then to the desired page.

I also use cookies to store tokens.

```
canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.tokenService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
  map(isAuth => {
   if (!isAuth) {
     this.router.navigate(['auth']).then();
     return false;
   }
   return true;
  })
);
```

}

```
const routes: Routes =  [
{
  path: 'auth',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  loadChildren: () => import('./main/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
},
{
  path: '', resolve: {mainInfo: MainResolverService}, component: MainComponent, children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)},
    {path: 'faq', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/faq/faq.module').then(m => m.FaqModule)},
    {path: 'cooperation-request', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/cooperation-request/cooperation-request-module').then(m => m.CooperationRequestModule)},
    {path: 'contact-us', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/contact-us/contact-us.module').then(m => m.ContactUsModule)},
    {path: 'mentors', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/mentors/mentors.module').then(m => m.MentorsModule)},
    {path: 'category', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/category/category.module').then(m => m.CategoryModule)},
    {path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule)},
    {path: 'webinar/:id/:title', loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/global/webinar/webinar.module').then(m => m.WebinarModule)},
    {path: 'user', canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./main/modules/secured/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)},
  ]
}
```

];

Comment: Have you set your login page as default route?

Comment: No, I also added a router

Comment: it looks like the `canActivate observable` is running before your app is finishing the authentication, so firstly `isAuth` is `false`, and then in turns to true and goes to the desired url. Can you show us `tokenService.isAuthenticated$`?

Comment: I do not think so because my guard does not run more than once and first goes to the login page and then the page opens.
When I see the source of the auth pages, the source of the login page is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the API is called on the browser and the API must be called in Express js.
You can call cookies in Express through the cookie-parser package.

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```